# How to compare two list of list with the same alphabet and get the max number and append them to another list?

Tags: python, list

I got this two list of list:

```
A=[[12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [2, 'w'], [3, 'Q'], [0, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'w'], [5, 'Q']]
B=[[12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [15, 'w'], [3, 'Q']]
```

and I want to compare these two lists by alphabet and append the list with the max number into a new list C?

```
C=[[12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [15, 'w'], [3, 'Q'],[12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [15, 'w'], [5, 'Q']]
```

EDIT:I got this code but it only outputs

```
C=[[12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [15, 'w'], [3, 'Q']]?

C = []
for g1, g2 in zip(a,b):
    line = []
    for e1, e2 in zip(g1, g2):
        line.append(max(e1, e2))
    C.append(line)
```

Comment: Good for you... Then what is holding you back to write the program?

Comment: BTW, both of those lists use the same alphabet, the [ISO basic Latin alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet).

Comment: Small tip : `B` should be a dict.

Comment: Will B ever contain duplicate keys? IOW, will there ever be 2 or more sublists in B that have the same letter?

Comment: No each letter is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) cannot work in this case, because elements of `B` can be used anywhere in `C`. The iterable returned by `zip` only has as many elements as the shortest list.

You need to keep `A`'s order in `C`, so `A` should stay a list but `B` should be a dict:

```
>>> A=[[12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [2, 'w'], [3, 'Q'], [0, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'w'], [5, 'Q']]
>>> B=[[12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [15, 'w'], [3, 'Q']]
>>> B = {l[1]:l for l in B}
>>> B
{'a': [12, 'a'], 'c': [0, 'c'], 'w': [15, 'w'], 'Q': [3, 'Q']}
```

You can then use a list comprehension to get the max values:

```
>>> [max(l, B[l[1]]) for l in A]
[[12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [15, 'w'], [3, 'Q'], [12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [15, 'w'], [5, 'Q']]
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a dictionary holding the max values in `B` taking care to ensure to deal with any possible duplicates in the list. Then create `C` using a list comprehension based on the the largest value found in `B` and the current value:

```
A = [[12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [2, 'w'], [3, 'Q'], [0, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'w'], [5, 'Q']]
B = [[12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [15, 'w'], [3, 'Q']]

max_values = {}

for count, value in B:
    try:
        max_values[value] = max(max_values[value], count)
    except KeyError:
        max_values[value] = count

C = [[max(count, max_values[value]), value] for count, value in A]

print C
```

Giving you:

```
[[12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [15, 'w'], [3, 'Q'], [12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [15, 'w'], [5, 'Q']]
```

In the example you gave, `B` contains unique values, but if there happened to be multiple entries for the same letter, this solution will ensure the maximum is used.